# How to calculate the total marks for online Examination system in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing simple online Examination system. while adding Questions Admin enter the Correct score and Negative score for that question. But my problem is how to get the correct and negative score of each question and total marks.I am unable to get the results.
Here below code is submitting test
**submittest.php**

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
session_start();
$tot=0;
$correct=0;
$wrong=0;
$ques='';
$answered=0;
$wrong_answered=0;
$resgiterno=$_POST['registerno'];
 //$id= $_SESSION['id'];



foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  $id=substr($key,7);
    $tot++;

 $answer=implode(",",$value);


 //if(dbSelect("questions","*","correct_option='$answer' and id='$id'",""))
 if($score_sql=mysql_query("select * from questions where correct_option='$answer' and id='$id'"))
 {
  $score=mysql_fetch_array($score_sql);


   $correct=$correct+$score['correct_score'];   
   $wrong=$wrong+$score['negative_score'];
//echo $val;
  $ques.=$id.",";

  }


}


$total_marks=$correct-$wrong;
//echo "total score is $total_marks";


echo "Congratulations you have Completed the Exam";


?>
```

**Here how Displaying Questions Code**

```
<div class="que_box_left"><div class="d1"><div class="option">a)</div><input name="answer_<?php echo $question['id']?>[]" type="checkbox" value="option_a" class="mar_ri" /></div>
<div class="d2"><?php echo $question['option_a'] ?></div></div>
<div class="que_box_left"><div class="d1"><div class="option">b)</div><input name="answer_<?php echo $question['id']?>[]" type="checkbox" value="option_b" class="mar_ri" /></div>
<div class="d2"><?php echo $question['option_b']?></div></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="que_box_left"><div class="d1"><div class="option">c)</div><input name="answer_<?php echo $question['id']?>[]" type="checkbox" value="option_c" class="mar_ri" /></div>
<div class="d2"><?php echo $question['option_c']?></div></div>
<div class="que_box_left"><div class="d1"><div class="option">d)</div><input name="answer_<?php echo $question['id']?>[]" type="checkbox" value="option_d" class="mar_ri" /></div>
<div class="d2"><?php echo $question['option_d']?>
</div>
```

**here how i send the data to above code submit-test.php**

```
$('.form_test_submit').live("click",function(){
    $.post("submit-test.php?testname="+testname,$('.form_test').serialize(),function(data){    
     alert(data);

    if(data=='Congratulations you have Completed the Exam')
      window.location.assign("results.php");
      /*
     else 
     window.location.assign("level.php?sid=<?php echo $student['sid'] ?>&eid=<?php echo $eid ?>&subid=<?php echo $subid ?>");
   */ });
   return false;
});
```

By that code i am unable to get the Exact Results. please Help me. Thanks In advance

Comment: Maybe you should do this in sql,post some sample data.

Comment: Yes. Injection still happens, and PHP's mysql_ methods are still deprecated.

Comment: how to do in SQL...@Mihai

Comment: Please explain what i have to do clearly.>@Strawberry

Comment: might this helps you [quiz](http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/php/php-quiz-application/156/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use session. On submission of true answer use session++ and for wrong use session--
and if you want to show both wrong and right answer you can use two sessions one for wrong and other is for right. On submission of true answer use right_session++ and for wrong ans use wrong_sesssion++.

Comment: but i have a correct score and negative score marks in DB. It should be calculated with DB marks. how can i do that

Comment: Can you send me table structures for both tables?

Comment: yeah sure. here i can i send.. @Umaie Hamid

Comment: email me at umair_hamid100@yahoo.com

Comment: In your database you are using correct score, and negative score. Are these fields applies for whole exam?

Comment: Yes.Its applied to whole exam

Comment: Please tell me @Umaie Hamid.

Comment: Sorry for reply late. You can use those columns for show the marks. Select all record from table and print an array. See if you can see the result in that array.