# Automatic marking

Tags: php, html, mysql

Am puzzled about how to make a system that can automatically mark.
Am using a variable $count in PHP and is the one storing data from the checked radio button.

I have not tried to check on how to do it and am just afraid of how to do it.

I have the following codes which out puts the data in radio buttons

```
    <?php

$get=mysql_query("select * from courses where courseid='".$cid."'");
while ($picked=mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    echo "<b>The questions for ".$picked['coursename']." are:</b><br><br>";
}

$query=mysql_query("select * from papers where cid='".$cid."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
    $count=1;
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "Qn ".$count.". ".$row['question']."<br><input type='radio' name='".$count."' value='A'>".$row['A']."<br><input type='radio' name='".$count."' value='B'>".$row['B']."<br><input type='radio' name='".$count."' value='C'>".$row['C']."<br><input type='radio' name='".$count."' value='D'>".$row['D']."<br><br>";
        $count++;
    }
}else{
    echo "No papar has been set yet for this paper.";
}

?>
<input type="submit" name="but" value="Submit Assessment">
```

and it outputs the following:

[image]

And the database is like:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by automatically mark in this scenario ?

Comment: When the student clicks the submit button, I want the system to calculate the marks and display they from which I will post them to database.

Comment: Ok .. Check these 2 SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610115/how-to-calculate-the-total-marks-for-online-examination-system-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312033/php-store-calculate-the-total-mark-from-radio-input

Comment: Thank you but let me just try their codes and see.

Comment: Yes .. Don't be afraid of trying new codes. If needed you can create a copy/backup of your php file before you start. Later if it doesn't work you can just replace that backup file with the edited one & get it back to how it was earlier. Simple :)

Comment: Do I deserve a credit or a vote upon my question?

Comment: Thank you so much.